# Compare two CSV files of different lengths to find matching values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare two sets of data and find matches.
I have one file (file1.csv) 1400 lines that looks like this:

```
ID
123
456
789
145
165
175
185
195
```

I have another file (file2.csv) around 46,000 lines that looks like this:

```
accountNumber, user, accountNumber2, address 
456,example@email.com,0,1 Lane
001,example1@email.com,175,2 Lane
002,example2@email.com,789,3 Lane
195,example3@email.com,0,4 Lane
123,example4@email.com,0,5 Lane
689,example5@email.com,0,6 Lane
003,example6@email.com,0,7 Lane
004,example7@email.com,0,8 Lane
```

I want use file1 ID's to match up with emails in file2.
The output I would like is a new file(file3) like:

```
ID,Email
123, example4@email.com
456, example@email.com
789, example2@email.com
145, Not found
165, Not found
175, example1@email.com
185, Not found
195, example3@email.com
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

file1_df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file2_df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

def search():
    for account_id in file1_df['account_id']:
        print("ID: ",account_id)
        id_loc = file1_df[file1_df['account_id'] == account_id].index.values
        print("id_loc",id_loc)

        try:
            accountNumber = file2_df[file2_df['accountNumber'] == account_id]['user'].values[0]
            print(accountNumber)
            accountNumber_loc = file2_df.loc[file2_df['accountNumber'] == account_id].index.values
            print(account_id, "Found at: ", accountNumber_loc)
            file1_df.loc[id_loc, "Located"] = accountNumber
        except Exception:
            pass
            try:
                accountNumber2 = file2_df[file2_df['accountNumber2'] == account_id]['user'].values[0]
                print(accountNumber2)
                accountNumber2_loc = file2_df.loc[file2_df['accountNumber2'] == account_id].index.values
                print(account_id, "Found at: ", accountNumber2_loc)
                file1_df.loc[id_loc, "Located"] = accountNumber2
            except Exception:
                print("Not Found")
                file1_df.loc[id_loc, "Located"] = "Not found"

search()
file1_df.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

I keep getting the error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

It seems like it almost works with small files but once I try with the real version I just keep getting the IndexError. Is there a better way to find these matches?

Comment: this is a join `pd.merge(file1_df ,file2_df ,left_on=['ID'],right_on=['accountNumber'],how='left')` my only add is that you may need to unnest your 2nd df so you can have one row per id as you seem to have two account numbers ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

As @Manakin already mentioned, it's just a simple join operation you require on your file1_df as the left reference.
Added the rest code to get you the data in your required format.

```
import pandas as pd

file1_df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file2_df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

file3_df = pd.merge(file1_df, file2_df, left_on=['ID'], right_on=['accountNumber'], how='left')['id', 'accountNumber'].rename(columns = {'accountNumber': 'Email'})
```